# ios push notification with Notification center

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, xcode7

In my push notification service, my server sending some unwanted alerts also for various reasons,. I want to show particular notification alone in my notification center.Is that possible to hide the notification from server to device notification center.

Comment: Your app has absolutely **no** control over the display of remote push notifications.  If you want control, you have to send silent notifications and have the app display local notifications as desired.  You'll have to live with the unreliability of app-wakeup if you go this route.

Comment: P.S.  You could also have server settings that the app could control.  That's up to your specific app.

Comment: we cant control to place notification in our notification pane through programmatically is it so?